# Компьютер запускается со 2го раза с новой оперативной памятью

Tags: ram, пк

Я купил себе новую оперативную память, 2 по 8гб, 1600MHz, DDR3, она полностью совместима с материнской платой, но когда я включаю компьютер, с начала он не отображает картинку / не реагирует ни на что, потом после выключения, я его включаю, и всё нормально бутится. В чем может быть проблема, какие логи стоит посмотреть, что настраивать в биосе? Стоит её вернуть(крайне не хотелось бы), или можно что-то сделать?

Comment: по классике - потестируйте память с помощью любого memtest'a, протрите контакты памяти (например, ластиком). Проверьте в биосе настройки памяти, может там "на грани" выставлен. На некоторых материнках есть индикатор (в два символа обычно), который показывает, на каком этапе зависло.

Comment: Да небось какая-нибудь гонщицкая память с нестандартным SPD, материнка сразу не понимает, как её запускать. Хотя я не очень разбираюсь. Но хорошо бы марку и модель памяти сказать